# What is the relationship between the windows in UIApplication and window in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, appdelegate

In an iOS Single View App project created using Xcode, the automatically generated `AppDelegate` has an instance variable called `window`:

```
// In AppDelegate.swift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  // ...
  var window: UIWindow?
  // ...
}
```

However, the `UIApplication` singleton of any iOS app also has some window-related properties:

```
open class UIApplication : UIResponder {
  // ...
  open var keyWindow: UIWindow? { get }
  open var windows: [UIWindow] { get }
  // ...
}
```

My guess:

- `windows` in `UIApplication` is just an array of length 1, and the only window in it is the `AppDelegate`'s window, and
- `keyWindows` is also `AppDelegate`'s window.

Is this correct? What is the relationship between the `window` of `AppDelegate` and the `windows` of `UIApplication`?

Answer (score 1):

Your guesses are correct for the typical app.

There are cases where an app may create and show additional windows. Or iOS may add additional windows to the app when using certain features. In these cases, the `windows` array will have more than one window (including the one referenced by the app delegate), and the keyWindow may be any one of those windows for some period of time (and not necessarily the app delegate's window).

Here is the documentation for the `UIApplicationDelegate window` property:

> This property contains the window used to present the app’s visual content on the device’s main screen.
>
> Implementation of this property is required if your app’s `Info.plist` file contains the `UIMainStoryboardFile` key. Fortunately, the Xcode project templates usually include a synthesized declaration of the property automatically for the app delegate. The default value of this synthesized property is `nil`, which causes the app to create a generic `UIWindow` object and assign it to the property. If you want to provide a custom window for your app, you must implement the getter method of this property and use it to create and return your custom window.

Comment: Will AppDelegate’s window ever change during the life time of a multi-window app?

Comment: Only if you write code to set a different window to the delegate's `window` property.